# how to activate Microsoft azure account?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am having professional license of visual studio 2015.
is there any way to activate Microsoft azure account using professional credit of VS 2015?

Thanks

Comment: Log in my.visualstudio.com,  navigate to benefits tab and find out if you have monthly Azure credit. If yes, just click activate to use your benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, If you want to active your Azure account with your  professional Visual studio Credit. You do have to following step.

**Steps**

1. > You need to convert your free trial to Pay As You Go subscription,
   >       then you will need to connect between [azure account](https://ms.portal.azure.com) and [VS account](https://my.visualstudio.com/Benefits)
2. > To make it connected, You need to submit a support ticket to the
   >       subscription team so that they may assist with the above mentioned
   >       issue to get it sorted For having support ticket refer [here](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/newsupportrequest)
3. > After successful activation You can receive the free credit according
   >   to your Visual Studio subscription type. Usually support team requires
   >   5-7 working days to activate.

**Note:**

> Once you active your Azure account with visual studio professional
>   subscription initially you need not to buy credit for this account ,
>   you would get free credit. You also can do it with your [visual studio account](https://my.visualstudio.com/Benefits). For more information you could refer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/member-offers/credit-for-visual-studio-subscribers/)

Comment: @kashif azmi try out the given steps I hope you could active azure with vs subscription easily.